# Bringing people into an Asterisk conference call

Tags: asterisk, voip

I'm using Asterisk 1.4 and am trying to work out a way to bring people into a conference call. In the ideal scenario two people would be talking and one of them would push some keys, then a phone number and then the three of them would be in a conference. From there they should be able to bring in other people as well.

This seems to be what the [Asterisk n-way call HOWTO](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+n-way+call+HOWTO) is trying to do, but it doesn't work quite properly for me. Here's what happens:
1. Internal person A calls person B
2. Person A presses *0, he is given a dial tone and person B is taken to a conference room
3. Person A calls person C and they can talk, and then person A presses `**`.
4. Person C is brought to the conference room, but person A is disconnected.

In the last step, A should be taken to the conference room as well.

[Here's](http://dpaste.com/hold/97072/) the relevant logs, where 230 is person A, 231 is person B, 207 is person C, and 282 is the conference room.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit of a necro, but i can't see your relevent logs.

Its not as fancy as *1 and **, but it should work in the same idea.  -- Make an extension that is a conference extension, anyone who calls ext 6000, gets placed in a conference call.

Person A calls Person B.
Person A and B talk, and then Person A decides Person C should be in on the call too. 
Person A blind-transfers Person B to extension 6000.
Person A Calls Person C, Briefs him, and blind-transfers Person C to extension 6000. 
Person A then Calls Extension 6000.

Rinse and repeat as many times as necessary -- or AIM your buddies to dial extension 6000.

Answer (score 1):

You need the meetme extension.  Configure a "room" using meetme.conf and assign it a pin and an extension.  Then configure the extension from the dialplan to call MeetMe application.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MeetMe is a good guide for getting it working.

When you dial into the conference extension, you can either set it up to go to one "room" only, or to ask the user to dial the room number, and then a PIN after to auth to that room.

It also gives you the option to become a manager, and kick people from the conf-call.  It's not easy to do this if you're doing 3way calls.

I never managed to get conf-calling working without MeetMe.

Answer (score 0):

GruffTech hits it.  One way or another, each conference participant-to-be needs to cause the conference app (MeetMe, Conference, etc) to be run, and the room number to be passed to it.  That can be as a single static extension, an extension prefix you setup that maps the dialed number to the conference room number, or something similar.

You can also route that extension or prefix to an AGI (Asterisk script) and have the script do whatever you want (consult a DB, check CID, etc) and issue the conference command. From an AGI script, joining a conference looks like this:
  http://help.cloudvox.com/faqs/reference/reference-for-php#manageconf

Usually the same thing can be run from a dialplan.

Finally, you can forcibly put a channel into a conference by sending an AMI event (like to place someone in conference regardless of where they are in a call, or to do it from a totally separate script).  Running the "Command" AMI event is the simplest way to do that, and can take the same conference & room arguments.

Troy